# Clojure lein-uberwar additional content in WEB-INF

Tags: clojure, war, leiningen

I can give lein-uberwar plugin a path to custom web.xml:

```
  :uberwar {:handler app-demo.core/app
            :web-xml "web.xml" 
            :name "app-demo.war"}
```

How can I in an **automated** way specify some additional content that goes into WEB-INF, for example applicationContext.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any file that you put under `war-resources` will be added to your war file (assuming default configuration for lein-uberjar). So for your example you need to put your `applicationContext.xml` file under `war-resources/WEB-INF` in your project.

You can customise the list of paths added to your war by setting [`:war-resources-paths`](https://github.com/luminus-framework/lein-uberwar/blob/master/src/leiningen/war.clj#L201-L204) in your project.clj.